# Setting an image as a tkinter window background

Tags: python, tkinter

I am Trying to set an image as the background of my Tkinter window and everything I try doesn't seem to work. Here's the code I have:

```
import random
import Tkinter # note use of caps
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os.path


window = Tk()
window.title('Ask If You Dare')
window.configure(background = '#007501')
```

Comment: In your code, you are only changing the color of the background. Where os the image you want to put as background? In any case, you could use a canvas to set your image.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background to be an image (without using canvas), use labels:

```
import random
import Tkinter # note use of caps
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os.path

window = Tk()
window.title('Ask If You Dare')

photo=PhotoImage(file="path/to/your/file")
l=Label(window,image=photo)
l.image=photo       #just keeping a reference
l.grid()
```